# How to set object member to immutable in java?

Tags: java, immutability, readonly

I want to make my class's object member to immutable.(Even to object member's member).

```
public class Bar {

    private String data;

    public Bar(String data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Foo {
    private Bar bar;

    public Foo(Bar bar){
        this.bar = bar;
        }

    public Bar getBar() {
        return bar;
    }
}
```

main for test

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Bar bar = new Bar("initial data");
    Foo foo = new Foo(bar);
    System.out.println(foo.getBar().getData()); // "initial data"
    foo.getBar().setData("changed data");
    System.out.println(foo.getBar().getData()); // "changed data"
}
```

In this example, foo's bar is readonly object field. But using getter method, I can access to that reference then change the data.

Finally foo's bar is changed.
Can I prevent change like this?

-edit-
Immutable class Couldn't has mutable class member?

Comment: The problem is not with `Foo`, it is really immutable. I.e. its member always refers to the same object. But your `Bar` is not immutable due to the setter method.

Comment: Thanks for response.
Normally, Bar class could used without Foo class. Bar class is not restricted to any contract. I am focusing to Foo's immutable object member.